# pivot_wider() arguments imply differing number of rows Eroor

Tags: r, data.table, pivot, tidyr

I have the following data.table object called `x`:

```
 month.option   som.month
  all.year        56.6%
     diff        -0.9%
```

and when I perform the following operation :

```
x %>% pivot_wider(names_from = month.option, values_from = som.month) %>%
                select(diff, everything()) %>%
                set_names(c("Dif vs MA", "SOM YTD", "SOM AA"))
```

I get the following error: `Error in data.frame(row = row_id, col = col_id) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2`. However I don't understand the reason since `x` is a 2x2 data.table. If anyone knows a possible issue that I am not seeing I will appreciate the correction.

As a side note, all the columns are of type `character`, if that is any useful info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` solution with same `pivot_wider()`. You are having issues because the function can not identify the rows properly. Creating an id is the solution:

```
#Code
df %>% mutate(id=1) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = month.option,values_from=som.month) %>%
select(-1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  all.year diff 
  <chr>    <chr>
1 56.6%    -0.9%
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(month.option = c("all.year", "diff"), som.month = c("56.6%", 
"-0.9%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use `pivot_wider`, we could do this without creating a new column by specifying the `values_fn` as `I`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = month.option, values_from = som.month, values_fn =  I)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  all.year diff    
#  <I<chr>> <I<chr>>
#1 56.6%    -0.9%
```

Or it can be also a function to get the `first` element

```
x %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = month.option, 
          values_from = som.month, values_fn =  first)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   all.year diff 
#  <chr>    <chr>
#1 56.6%    -0.9%
```

---

However, these kind of problems can be easily tackled with `transpose` from `data.table`

```
data.table::transpose(x, make.names = 'month.option')
#  all.year  diff
#1    56.6% -0.9%
```

---

Or use `deframe` with `as_tibble_row` which would be more direct

```
library(tibble)
deframe(x) %>%
   as_tibble_row
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  all.year diff 
#  <chr>    <chr>
#1 56.6%    -0.9%
```

---

Or another option is to convert the first column to rownames, do the transpose with `t` and convert to `tibble` (or `data.frame`)

```
x %>% 
    column_to_rownames('month.option') %>% 
     t %>%
     as_tibble
# A tibble: 1 x 2    
#   all.year diff 
#  <chr>    <chr>
#1 56.6%    -0.9%
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(month.option = c("all.year", "diff"), som.month = c("56.6%", 
"-0.9%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `data.table` we can also use `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(x, rowid(month.option)~month.option, value.var = 'som.month')

#   month.option all.year  diff
#1:            1    56.6% -0.9%
```